# Method not found exception on MethodExpression.invoke()

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, el, methodnotfound

I have a need to programmatically call/invoke a method in one of my backing beans.  I've looked at several examples, and from what I can see, this "should" work.

**My code:**

```
UIData data = (UIData)component;
fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
elc = fc.getELContext();

elFactory = fc.getApplication().getExpressionFactory();
mexp =
    elFactory.createMethodExpression(elc, data.getValueExpression("value").getExpressionString(), Result.class, new Class[]{});
Object methodResult = mexp.invoke(elc, null);
```

The "data.getValueExpresssion("value").getExpressionString() returns the string:

```
#{reports.customer}
```

**Info about the bean I'm calling** (*don't know if these are relevant*):
    Class's managed bean name is "report"
    Class is in Session-scope
    Class implements Serializable
    The access modifier of the method I'm calling is
    There are no parameters in the method signature

**Method I'm trying to invoke:**

```
public Result getCustomer() {
    Result result = null;
    try {
        ...perform database call
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e);
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Stack-Trace Excerpt**

```
SEVERE: javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: Method not found: com.npp.beans.reports.SharebackReportsBean@1ebf0d3.customer()
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: Method not found: com.npp.beans.reports.SharebackReportsBean@1ebf0d3.customer()
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:98)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:98)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:311)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:781)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1246)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:77)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:114)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:308)
...
Caused by: javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: Method not found: com.npp.beans.reports.SharebackReportsBean@1ebf0d3.customer()
    at com.sun.el.util.ReflectionUtil.getMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:155)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:231)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:297)
    at com.npp.business.TableToExcelManager.initExcelWorker(TableToExcelManager.java:247)
    at com.npp.beans.reports.SharebackReportsBean.exportToExcel(SharebackReportsBean.java:439)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:234)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:297)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:84)
    ... 26 more
Mar 23, 2011 11:29:34 AM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase execute
WARNING: #{reports.exportToExcel}: javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: Method not found: com.npp.beans.reports.SharebackReportsBean@1ebf0d3.customer()
javax.faces.FacesException: #{reports.exportToExcel}: javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: Method not found: com.npp.beans.reports.SharebackReportsBean@1ebf0d3.customer()
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:114)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:311)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:781)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1246)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:77)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:114)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:308)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
```

Any help on this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're attempting to treat a value expression as a method expression. This isn't going to work. Value expressions points to getter methods (and thus `get` can be omitted) while method expressions points to action methods, possibly taking an extra argument. Since you already have the `ValueExpression`, just get value from it directly instead of attempting to treat it like a `MethodExpression`.

```
Result result = (Result) data.getValueExpression("value").getValue(elc);
```

You should not change the EL string in the view. Just keep it `value="#{reports.customer}"`. Otherwise it won't work in the normal view.